# Solving the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y^3}{2(xy^2-x^2)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How can we solve the equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y^3}{2(xy^2-x^2)}$$

I get the idea of dividing by $y^2$, But it doesn't become any more solvable (not homogenous).
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{2(x-\frac{x^2}{y^2})}$$

Substituting $\frac{x}{y} = t$ causes even more complications.

I get an idea of the question to convert into homogenous, but cant form the equation. Please give me a hint!

Comment: Yes, But the same problem occurred as with $\frac{dy}{dx}$, I got a mix of terms.

Comment: Try putting $y^2 = t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question!

Given:
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{2x}{y}-\frac{2x^2}{y^3}$$
$$=>\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{2x}{y}=-\frac{2x^2}{y^3}$$
On dividing by $-x^2$,
$$=>\frac{dx}{dy}\frac{(-1)}{x^2}+\frac{2}{xy}=\frac{2}{y^3}$$
Substituting $v=\frac{1}{x}$; $\frac{dv}{dy}=\frac{dx}{dy}\frac{(-1)}{x^2}$gives:
$$\frac{dv}{dy}+\frac{2v}{y}=\frac{2}{y^3}$$

Now simply use the method for solving linear differential equations.

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: One question, in this linear equation, is $P = \frac{1}{y}$ and $Q = \frac{2}{y^3}$ ?

Comment: That's right! Make sure the function involves constants as well (2/y) @samjoe

Comment: @samjoe $P = \frac{2}{y}$

Comment: @MaxPayne Thanks; your solution is, however, more intuitive imo.

Comment: @Kugelblitz Yes LDE are mostly hard to find for me.

Answer (score 1):

By putting $y^2 = t$, it will reduce to homogenous:

$$\frac{t'}{2y} = \frac{ty}{xt-x^2}$$
$$\therefore \ t' = \frac{2t^2}{xt-x^2}$$

Now you can divide by $x^2$, and put $t=ux.$